# GitLab WEB Browser Session timeout

Tags: user-interface, session, gitlab

I'm running GitLab on Centos 7. GitLab was installed using YUM.
The initial gitlab version was 1.7.12.2.

The problem is with the WEB interface of the GitLab installation.
I'm trying to get the browser session to timeout so that it forces you to login again after a certain period.
I have noticed that a change request was implemented, so I upgraded from 1.7.12.2 to 1.7.14.3 using yum update.
Under the Administration setting (in Web UI) I can now see the extra parameter where you can set the timeout. I have now changed it tt two minutes(for testing so I don't have to wait so long), but it simply does not work.
I have also tried something bigger - 5 minutes - not working.

I have also done a gitlab-ctl stop, then gitlab-ctl reconfigure and then gitlab-ctl start. The new value still shows, but the browser session still does not timeout.

I have also created a new CentOS 7 installation from scratch, installed GitLab via yum with version 1.7.14.3 - this is as-is from the installation - so no previous upgrade problems or similar problems.

I have tried different browsers (FireFox and Chrome) on Windows 7/8, Even Mac. I have also cleared the browser cookies to make sure it gets the latest after the updates. No change in behavior.

Changing the time still has no effect....

Anybody with an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The truth is I think there is a bug in the current session expiration mechanism. See https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/2129

Short answer, your not crazy ;) Hopefully we can resolve this issue shortly.

Comment: Tks for the feedback - I have upgraded last night to version 8.0.3 and it is now working as expected!

Comment: I'm glad it works now. Thank you for commenting on the issue tracker, too. We'll test a bit more to ensure this does work for everyone.